# How to remove spaces after table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to remove spaces after a certain element? I have this code.

```
</table>"&nbsp;&nbsp;"
```

The &nbsp are variable. I'm trying this.

```
$("table").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).children();
    text = text.replace('"&nbsp;"', "");
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

Comment: Standard HTML uses insignificant whitespace.  Only one of these spaces will be shown, anyways.

Comment: your $('table') not contains space char, try to souround them inside a span, then find this span, and remove it, or remove its html child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the text of the parent.  Note that using `.text` returns spaces where `&nbsp;` are in the html.  This actually makes it easier to replace.

```
$("table").each(function () {
    $(this).parent().text(function (_, text) {
        return text.replace(/"\s+"/, '');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/wrnBG/

Answer (score 0):

see [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

that function will help you select the rogue text node and you can remove it from there